# Dropdown menu + slideshow in content z-index issue

Tags: css, z-index

I'm having a problem where a slideshow (using jQuery Cycle) gets rendered in front of a dropdown menu in the navigation.

The weird thing is that everything works in Internet Explorer but in Firefox, Chrome and other decent browsers.

I suppose this has to do with z-index, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

You can view the code on http://jsfiddle.net/aEdAi/.

- **Try hovering the third navigation menu item to see the dropdown menu**.
- You can set class="hover" on the third `<li>` in the navigation using Firebug to visually ‘lock’ the hover state and debug.

How can I fix this? The dropdown menu always needs to be on top of the slideshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi if you set your div intro-wrapper with

`#intro-wrapper {
height:390px;
position:relative;
z-index:0;
}`

it work...